# Write WCF XML Message to Dictionary

Tags: xml, wcf, web-services, dictionary

I'm very new to using WCF and im trying to handle an xml message.

from what Ive experienced so far I would normally receive XML formatted like this.

```
<data>
  <name>Jim</name>
  <age>28</age>
  <location>London</location>
</data>
```

I would then assign each element "name" "age" etc like below

```
[DataContract(Namespace="",Name="data")]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember(Name = "age")]
    public string Age;
    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public string Location;

}
```

But the message im currently working with is in the following format and im unsure how to handle it.

```
<dict>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>Jim</string>
  <key>Age</key>
  <string>28</string>
  <key>Location</key>
  <data>London</data>
</dict>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to generate a new xml document from the one you receive, like this:

```
var oldMessage = XDocument.Parse(message_string);
var newMessage = new XDocument(new XElement("data",
    oldMessage.Root.Elements("key").Select(el =>
        new XElement(el.Value.ToLower(), 
            el.ElementsAfterSelf().First().Value))));
```